# Mysterious Table Row Padding/Margin

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm having an issue in which I can see some mysterious padding/margin on a table row which I do not require, but am unable to remove.

Please see screenshot below of the area highlighted with a blue box:

[image]

The code is here:

https://codepen.io/mattsmith/pen/GWZNVN

I have tried many things such as `margin: 0`, `border-spacing: 0`, `padding: 0` etc. Can anybody please help me out here? As I need the blue box to be flush with the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `img` is <strike>an inline element</strike> "replaced content" which will inherit `line-height`, and you're seeing the line-height spacing. You can fix it by using `line-height: 0;` or `font-size: 0;` on the parent, or setting either `display: block;` or `vertical-align: top` on the image.

```css
* {
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid red;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-weight: normal;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
img.banner {
  /* or either of these */
  /* display: block; */
  /* vertical-align: top; */
}
```

```html
<body style="padding: 50px; background: #f7faf9">
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 20px; width: 100%; max-width: 800px;">
  <tr>
    <th><img style="float: left; width: 70px" src="http://i.imgur.com/LsRs9OY.png"></th>
    <th><p style="text-align: right; font-size: 14px">February 14, 2017<br>Order <b>#4020</b></p></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="padding-top: 25px; line-height: 0;" colspan="2"><img style="width: 100%" class="banner" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/zcom-media/sites/a0i0L00000QylPjQAJ/media/mediamanager/media_page_banner.jpg"></th>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th style="background: #35a0c6; padding-top: 25px;" colspan="2"></th>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: I never knew this, I suppose you learn something new every day. Thank you!

Comment: Technically it is not a real inline element, but a replaced element https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/. The fix provided works well however. Edit: I am really not trying to stalk you Michael :-)

Comment: @Christoph hello again! :) I do appreciate the feedback, it makes me a better developer and SO a better community. I forgot what type of element the `img` was and have seen it referred to (here and other places) as `inline` so I just went with that.